# PHP Native Extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I have a set of classes and methods that I would like to see accessible from any use of PHP on a given system and would like to package this like an extension, even though it is not written in C. The classes and methods are also packaged with a shell script or two that have the `SUID` bit set. The classes would need to have access to these regardless of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

From what I have read the `auto_prepend` option for `php.ini` or `.htaccess` seem like the only option. Is there a better way to do this? Will I run into re-declaration issues if I use auto-prepend (including or requiring a file I'm assuming would cause the auto-prepend to fire again)?

Comment: I do use auto_prepend scripts for some tasks, but only because each declaration is deferred with a `if (!function_exists` or `!defined(` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at namespaces!
You can put all your classes in the same namespace, without interfering with the rest of the system.

Do not try to build a extension, if you want to package your library, have a look at [PHAR](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php).

Comment: Namespaces dont really address the issue at hand, which is to ensure that the classes and methods **are** available to all uses throughout the system. They are definitely a best practice in coding, but not really relavent to the issue at hand. Packaging the library is definitely something that I'd like to do, but I don't want to require it everywhere. This code should be more of less like an extension of the language for this use case

Comment: I use my framework on several sites on my server. I do do ditribute, but place a symlink on each site, and have the library only 'installed' once. Namespaces do the rest

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but namespaces are only an organizational tactic as best I understand. They are great; I use them, but they don't have anything to do with what methods/classes are available for you to use before you ever have an `include` or `require`. Is there some sort of magic (I guess autoloading well implemented) that you are using to make this available to your code?

Comment: Of course, my library has a autoloader with a mapper, that maps namespaces to locations, and includes classes as they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Put your classes/files somewhere on your server and set `php.ini`'s `include_path` to also include location of these files. Alternatively, as you stateed, you can use `auto_prepend_file` to enforce, but this **VERY BAD IDEA** if you are not using namespaces. Sooner or later you face name conflicts. Still not sure why you do not convert all into classes and use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: putting it in the `include_path` makes it available, but it must be `require`d or `include`d into each file. This code is more or less an addition to the language and should just be available in the same way that methods from an actual extension are globally available without additional includes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Still, enforcing inclusion with `auto_prepend_file` hit the performance. Is this really something you want to achieve? What is the problem in including it by hand when needed? Why you do not use autoloading?

Comment: Log4PHP is greedy with autoloading and has it's own autoloader so I can't use it for some of my apps.  We *could* just stick the code in the `include_path` and include it by hand and it will solve the issue, but was hoping not to. I am having a rather hard time justifying this though, so perhaps I re-evaluate what we are trying to accomplish.